# Shifter clicks in but chain stays on the largest cog, when riding

Tags: shimano, gears

I am able to change (click through) the shifter but the chain stays on the largest cog and does not move (This happens only when riding) but the gears shift as usual when the bike is stationary and I turn the pedals with my hand.

The bike is new, about a month old, everything worked well until last week and no, I'm not able to push the derailleur with my hand. I had a problem before when I was not able to shift (shifters won't click into the 3rd) into the 3rd gear (the largest cog), this was corrected when I took it to a bike mechanic. Now (about 4 days later) I've got a problem shifting between 2nd and the 3rd. Sometimes it shifts and most of the time it doesn't (shifting into and out of the 1st works fine). Btw I lubricated the chain after I got back from the bike mechanic.

Comment: Are you easing up as you shift on the bike? Chain tension can keep the derailer from moving. Try shifting on the bike while you pedal with no effort (for instance as you coast down a hill). Can you shift then?

Comment: no, the chain tension remains pretty much the same. Could it be that the derailleur does not move enough. BTW its the front derailleur.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Are you able to push the deraileur cage with your hand while slowly revolving pedals, with the bike off the ground?  Is this an old bike or a new bike?  Did it ever work right since you've had it?  Was it a sudden failure or a progressive failure?

Comment: hello, the bike is new (about a month old), everything worked well untill last week and no, Im not able to push the deraileur with my hand. I had a problem before when I was not able to shift (shifters wont click into the 3rd) into the 3rd gear (the largest cog), this was corrected when I took it to a bike mechanic. Now (about 4days later) Ive got a problem shifting between the 2nd and the 3rd. Sometimes it shifts and most of the time it doesn't (shifting into and out of the 1st works fine). Btw i lubricated the chain after I got back from the bike mechanic.

Comment: Sounds like it simply needs adjustment.

Comment: If the bike's only a month old you should take it to the shop and have the necessary adjustments done. The first service should normally be for free or for a minimal fee.

Answer (score 2):

Given its only a month old - return to the shop for the first "tune-up" which is standard in most parts of the world.

If you bought the bike on line, you can either learn to do it yourself or take it a bike shop and pay for a tuneup.  Depends on your mechanical aptitude.

Sounds like your bike mechanic visit missed something.